Why Doesn't my mac recognize that I have pandas installed?
I have been trying to install some python libraries (ex: pandas) and I end up with this error in vscode:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I have multiple versions of python on my mac and i really do not know what the problem is and it's making me go insane. I tried a lot of solutions that I find here and there but it does not seem to work.
I have python 3.12.3/3.12.2/3.9.6 and I am pretty sure when I checked that the libraries are installed.
I am fairly new to coding in general and would love some assistance on this.
I tried pyenv but I am not sure that it is working properly in vscode.
I tried installing all the libraries I need on all the versions of python I have and it still does not recognize it being installed.
I tried homebrew.

I would try <path_to_python> -m pip install pandas or potentially if you like the python on your path, python -m pip install pandas. Note that I never run a bare pip any more.

If you're using VS Code, make sure the Python interpreter you have selected is the same one for which you installed pandas. You can use the command py --version in the terminal to determine which Python is used when you run pip. Once you have that info, you can run Python: Select Interpreter from VS Code (or click on the Python version in the bottom-right corner). The most foolproof approach aside from that, as @JonSG suggests, is to run py -m pip instead of just pip whenever you need to install a package.


Open new system console and type python3 -m pip list and see if pandas is here
Open VSCode console, type python3 -m pip list and see if pandas is here

If pandas is listed in only in first scenario, check your VSCode pythonpath:

check if you have virtual environment set up, or is it using your global python environmnet.
if you don't use virtual environments, I think it's good time to start :D, it's simple and effective: Python venv

